# Remove slash fromJSON array

Tags: jquery, json

So there are questions like this, but this is slightly different. My JSON array holds an image url:

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/329207/screenshots/2798176/bemocs_rei_dribbble.jpg.

When I parse the JSON with jquery, the img src returns with a slash (/) at the end:

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/329207/screenshots/2798176/bemocs_rei_dribbble.jpg/

So I get an error and the image cannot be loaded. How can I remove that one slash?

Here is my code for my json parser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('scripts/json/articles.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            parent = $("<div class='card'/>");
            a = $("<a href=" + data['articles']['0'].Link + " target='_target'/>")
            li = $("<li class='bottom-description'/>");

            parent.append(a);

            a.append("<img src=" + data['articles']['0'].Image + "/>");
            a.append(li);

            li.append("<p class='title'>" + data['articles']['0'].Title + "</p>");
            li.append("<h3 class='desc'>" + data['articles']['0'].Description + "</h3>");
            $('.card-section').append(parent);
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: The slash comes from `"/>"`

Comment: @tkausl, wow that is remarkbly dumb on my part! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to put the image source in quotes. The "/" is coming from the "/>".

The solution is to replace line 10 with ...

```
a.append("<img src='" + data['articles']['0'].Image + "' />");
```

Notice the single quote added next to "src=" and "/>".

Answer (score 1):

```
   a.append("<img src=" + data['articles']['0'].Image + "/>");
```

Outputs `<img src=url/>`. Thus you get url/ as src.
Minimum change is to add a space before / but better practice is to also add quotes.

```
   a.append("<img src='" + data['articles']['0'].Image + "' />");
```

Same here:

```
a = $("<a href='" + data['articles']['0'].Link + "' target='_target'/>")
```

Once you have spaces in values, quotes are necessary.